# using private variable of a class in a methode of a subclass

Tags: java, inheritance, subclass, getter-setter, super

```
public class B {
    private int y ;

    public B(int y){
        this.y = y;
    }

    public int gety(){
        return y;
    }
}

public class C extends B{
    int y,z;
    public C(int y, int z ){
        super(y);
        this.z = z;
    }

    public int m3(){
        System.out.println(gety());
        return this.z*super.gety(); 
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        B b = new B(10);
        C c = new C(2,3);

        System.out.println(super.gety());
        System.out.println(c.m3());
    }
}
```

the result is :

```
10
2
6
```

First , sorry for my english
My question is why i didn't have as a result "30" in place of "6" , because i want from the m3 methode to return the value of z multiplied by the value of y inherited from class B , and why  System.out.println(super.gety()); prints "2" in place of "10"

Comment: this code will not compile because of this line :         System.out.println(super.gety());
--- you cannot use super in a static method like that

Comment: A suggestion that will help readability of your code: use different variable names (instead of `int y` in `B` and `C` classes). Also, as Oussama points out, the code as posted does not compile.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating **two different** objects.

1. B that has y value = 10
2. C that has y value = 2 and z = 3

The b and c objects you have created have no relationship between them.
So when you call `c.m3()` it multiplies 2*3.

You do not need to create a B object,
since you assign the y value of C object by super().
Instead you just have to create a C object with values 10 and 3.

Also another problem is that on class C you have `int y, z;`.

1. They are not private when they should be.
2. Y value is passed on the parent class B, so there is no need for the y value.